# display first set of result in row

Tags: php, arrays

I want to iterate an array of data using foreach loop.

However, I want the first 4 results to display two items per row.Thereafter I want the rest of the data to display I item per row

i found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309865/display-5-array-items-per-row-in-a-html-table)

```
$data = range(1, 30);
for($count = 0; $count < count($data);)
{
    echo "<tr>\n";
    for($i = 0; $count < count($data) && $i < 2; $count++, $i++) {
        echo "\t<td>$data[$count]</td>\n";
    }
    for(; $i < 2; $i++) {
        echo "\t<td>-</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

how the problem with this code is that it displays all the data in rows of two.i however only want the first 4 results to display that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$data = range(1, 30);

for($count = 0; $count < count($data); ++$count){
    if($count < 4){
        if($count % 2 == 0){
            echo "<tr><td>" . $data[$count] . "</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td>" . $data[$count] . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<tr><td>" . $data[$count] . "</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

[Here's the demo](https://ideone.com/9gugUt)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the already incremented `$i` variable twice.

`$i` is never `< 2`

Add this instead

```
for($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++) {
    echo "\t<td>-</td>\n";
}
```

[Test here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ce4d2ea7992b9bef552f4c646df45e45aae92d1)

Comment: hello JazzCat-sorry i did not explain myself properly. i only want the first 4 results from the array to display in rows of 2. thereafter, i want the rest of the data to display in rows of 1

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$data = range(1, 30);
for($count = 0; $count < count($data); $count++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    if($count < 2) {
       for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
          echo "<td>" . $data[$count] . "</td>";
          if($i == 1) {
             echo "</tr><tr>";
          }
       }
    } else {
       echo "<td>" . $data[$count] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
echo '<table border=1>';
$data = range(1, 30);
for($count = 0; $count < count($data); $count++){
  echo "<tr>\n";
  if($count < 4) {
    echo "\t<td>$data[$count]</td>\n";
    $count++;
    echo "\t<td>$data[$count]</td>\n";
  } else {
    echo "\t<td colspan=2>$data[$count]</td>\n";
  }
  echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo '</table>';
```